# Rails - is it possible to have a shortcut within a model for its nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nested

This might be a stupid question but it's wracked my head for a while...

So.. I have 2 models: (1) user, and (2) profile. The profile is associated to user via the following relationships:

```
(1) user has_one :profile
(2) profile belongs_to user
```

It is the standard relationship for user and profile within the devise system. Anyways, usually I access the user's name through the following nested attributes:

```
"user.profile.name"
```

is it possible to create a "virtual" attribute within the user model that links to this attribute within the profile model? I would like to call "`user.profile.name`" through "`user.name`".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is: [`delegate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate)

```
class User < ...
  delegate :name, to: :profile

   # The rest of your class
end
```

This will expose the `name` method from the Profile class to your User class